# Vue: pug language has not been recognized in .vue template

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

From the Vue [documentation](https://vue-loader-v14.vuejs.org/en/configurations/pre-processors.html#templates):

> Processing templates is a little different, because most webpack
>   template loaders such as pug-loader return a template function instead
>   of a compiled HTML string. Instead of using pug-loader, we can just
>   install the original pug.

**TestComponent.vue**:

```
<template lang="pug">
  div
    h2 {{ message }}
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        message: 'Done!!! Done...'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**main.js**:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import TestComponent from './../components/TestComponent/TestComponent.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(TestComponent)
});
```

Error:

```
NonErrorEmittedError: (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) 
  Error compiling template:

  div
    h2 {{ message }}

  - Component template requires a root element, rather than just text.
```

Used dependencies versions:

- "webpack": "^4.7.0"
- "vue": "^2.5.16"
- "vue-loader": "^15.2.4",
- "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.16",
- "pug": "^2.0.3"

Comment: Install `pug-loader`: https://github.com/pugjs/pug-loader

Comment: It says in [the documentation](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#pug) you need to use [pug-plain-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug-plain-loader)

Comment: Note: the [documentation link](https://vue-loader-v14.vuejs.org/en/configurations/pre-processors.html#templates) you've provided is for vue-loader v14 but you're using v15.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set up Webpack to use the Pug language loader, otherwise your template is being parsed as HTML, and your template indeed as HTML doesn't have a root tag (a single html element that surrounds all other elements).

You need to set this up: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug-loader

According to a comment you might also need: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug-plain-loader

Comment: @TakesiTokugawaYD I"m having the same problem but have all of the suggested loaders installed with their respective rules don't seem to solve it. Does the rule need to go inside the vue loader test under "options"?

Comment: @PeterT, No. Please refer [this working config](https://controlc.com/7445e25a) (for webpack 4.X.X).

Comment: @TakesiTokugawaYD Ah, thank you. I realized my problem was that I am using electron-webpack, and custom modifications per webpack rules are per-module, so I was only applying the pug rule to the `main` webpack entry and not the `renderer`.

Comment: You need `pug-plain-loader` rather than `pug-loader` if you are using `vue-loader` (which is typically used with Vue and Webpack, [see docs](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#pug)).